# Trying to understand PointCloud2 msg

Tags: laser, sensor-msgs, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Can someone please post a clear explanation of how to understand pointcloud2 message? I want to get x,y,z point from the message and I found a solution to do that, but I am not able to understand why there are so many numbers in data field?

Can someone please explain?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273182/trying-to-understand-pointcloud2-msg/) by [krishna43](https://answers.ros.org/users/22267/krishna43/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2017-10-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-10-16**:
What is the solution that you found? I think that people may have a hard time explaining it if they don't know what it is...

**Comment by [krishna43](https://answers.ros.org/users/22267/krishna43/) on 2017-10-18**:
https://answers.ros.org/question/202787/using-pointcloud2-data-getting-xy-points-in-python/

look at that question. that  helped me. @jayess

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-10-18**:
So, do you not need an explanation any more?

**Comment by [krishna43](https://answers.ros.org/users/22267/krishna43/) on 2017-10-18**:
@jayess I need an explanation of PointCloud2 data format. I got the result i want by blindly copying the code snippet, but i don't know what it means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `data` field of a PointCloud2 message contains the list of points encoded as a byte stream, where each point is a `struct`. The format of the points in an individual PointCloud2 message is defined by the `fields`, which is a list of [sensor_msgs/PointField](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/PointField.html) objects. In order to turn the data back into individual points, it has to be deserialized.  The PointCloud library has defined methods that do this automatically (in Python, you'd use `pc2.read_points`.) Under the hood, these methods use memory reinterpretation to transform the byte stream to a list of points (e.g. Python's `struct.unpack()` or reinterpret casting in C++).

The advantage of the byte stream representation is that it's a compact way to transport the data that is extremely flexible, allowing any arbitrary struct to be used for the points. The disadvantage is that the message unreadable without deserialization.

---

Originally posted by [Ed Venator](https://answers.ros.org/users/2636/ed-venator/) with karma: 1185 on 2017-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4